# Regex to disallow more than 1 dash consecutively

Tags: regex

1. How can I disallow `--` (more than 1 consecutive -)? e.g. `ab--c`
2. `-` at the back of words not allow, e.g. `abc-`
3. `-` at start of words not allow, e.g. `-abc`

`^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$` is what I have so far.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
^(?!-)(?!.*--)[A-Za-z0-9-]+(?<!-)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^             # Anchor at start of string
(?!-)         # Assert that the first character isn't a -
(?!.*--)      # Assert that there are no -- present anywhere
[A-Za-z0-9-]+ # Match one or more allowed characters
(?<!-)        # Assert that the last one isn't a -
$             # Anchor at end of string
```

Comment: Sorry, this also does not match abd-

Comment: @Sachin: As it shouldn't. The OP is listing three conditions he wants to disallow. (If he wanted to allow dashes at the start/end, why would he have mentioned them at all?)

Comment: Firefox 4 errors out on this one.  `^[^-]+(?!.*--).+[^-]+$` does work. Tested with http://jsbin.com/ujoxu3 .

Comment: @Martijn, unfortunately yours does not match if the total length is less than 3 characters.

Comment: @Brian: you’re right. I just can’t figure out why Firefox refuses Tim’s.

Comment: @Martijn, apparently [javascript does not support negative lookbehind](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript).

Comment: @Brian: yes, that’s it (thanks for the link, interesting article).  One way of solving it is by separately checking for one and two-character strings:  `^([^-]{0,2}|[^-]+(?!.*--).*[^-]+)$` (http://jsbin.com/ujoxu3/2 )

Comment: @Martijn, persionally I would prefer to avoid all these "lookarounds" as they tend to run slower. I don't see any room for a pathological case in Tim's answer but the negative lookahead/lookbehind are unnecessary all the same.

Comment: @Brian: I agree that it would be nicer without lookarounds.  But I can’t see a way to avoid them _while keeping requirement 1 in mind_. If you try yours with http://jsbin.com/ujoxu3/3/, you’ll see that they fail.

Comment: @Martijn: Mine, like Tim's answer and the starting point provided in the question, only allows alpha numeric characters and hyphen. if you want to any characters, then it can be simply modified as follows `^[^-]+(-[^-]+)*`

Comment: @Brian: I see — unfortunately, I had to go shortly after posting my answer (it was getting late), and now I can’t remove my downvote anymore. :-\

Answer (score 40):

`^[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$`

Using this regular expression, the hyphen is only matched just inside the group. This hyphen has the `[A-Za-z0-9]+` sub-expression appearing on each side. Because this sub-expression matches on one or more alpha numeric characters, its not possible for a hyphen to match at the start, end or next to another hyphen.

Comment: That's clever! Probably easier to understand than all my lookaround stuff.

Comment: @Sachin: As I understand the OP, that's exactly what he wants. He could be more explicit, though.

Comment: @Tim - Eeeesshhh... Totally misunderstood the question. @Brian - Absolutely this works. Thats why I was trying to match -abd and abd- in my regex... Thanks and sorry.

Comment: @Brian: you seem to have overlooked the OP’s first requirements: that it disallow consecutive hyphens.

Comment: @Martijn: No, it works fine. The hyphen is only ever matched just inside the group as a single hyphen character and must always be preceded and followed by at least one alphanumeric character. It only failed your test because you were testing with spaces and punctuation, which the question implied were not allowed (by the provded starting point). If you want to include those then use `^[^-]+(-[^-]+)*`

Comment: @Brian: you’re right.  It is indeed more elegant (and faster) than lookaheads.  +1  :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$

^[a-zA-Z0-9]     /*Starts with a letter or a number*/
(?!.*--)         /*Doesn't include 2 dashes in a row*/
[a-zA-Z0-9-]*    /*After first character, allow letters or numbers or dashes*/
[a-zA-Z0-9]$     /*Ends with a letter or a number*/
```

**Matches:**

Re-play / 
Re-play-ed

**Doesn't Match:**

Replay- / Re--Play / -Replay

Answer (score 1):

Try: `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-]{1})*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Regex101 link: https://regex101.com/r/xZ2g6p/1

This allows only one hyphen inbetween two set of characters and blocks it at the beginning & at the end of the character set.

Comment: What do you think the quantifier `{1}` does ? Is the hyphen a special character outside of a character class ? As an aside, nothing more under the sun since Brian Reichle's answer from 2011.

Answer (score 0):

If “-” is not allowed at the beginning nor end of the string, you are searching for a sequence of “one or more alanum, followed by one or more group(s) of one dash followed by 1 or more alanum”

```
/[0-9A-Z]+(-[0-9A-Z]+)+/
```

Simple is a valuable motto with regular expressions.
(nota : to search small case characters, add them. I didn't for clarity)