# Check whether an input string contains a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, validation

My end goal is to validate an input field. The input may be either alphabetic or numeric.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that.

Comment: Please edit your question title, to something more accurate like "jQuery input validate only alphabetic characters" since your description leads to none answer on "how to find numbers in a string", therefore it results in an irrelevant search result for our community. Thanks!

Comment: Edited "jQuery" out of the question title, and replaced with "Javascript".

Comment: @VKen, It is not necessary to put tags on title.

Comment: @Starx noted, I'm just keeping the format the question poster started with.

Comment: ***For newcomers :*** The exact solution for this question is here =>https://stackoverflow.com/a/28813213/15823478 :)

Answer (score 497):

If I'm not mistaken, the question requires "contains number", not "is number". So:

```
function hasNumber(myString) {
  return /\d/.test(myString);
}
```

Comment: this solution doesn't take into account non-integer numbers like 3.2 or 1e4

Comment: It does. Check in console: hasNumber("check 3.2 or 1e4") = true vs 
hasNumber("check no numbers") = false. Because 3.2 and 1e4 contain numbers in itself.

Comment: Why is this answer not on the top?

Comment: I tried putting the /\d/ in "" - that was stupid, just writing this in case someone else makes the same mistake

Comment: More information about the RegExp `.test` method can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 129):

You can do this using javascript. No need for Jquery or Regex

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

While implementing

```
var val = $('yourinputelement').val();
if(isNumeric(val)) { alert('number'); } 
else { alert('not number'); }
```

Update: To check if a string has numbers in them, you can use regular expressions to do that

```
var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
if (matches != null) {
    alert('number');
}
```

Comment: `matches != null` means not `undefined` or `null` while `matches !== null` means specifically not `null` but passes `undefined`.

Comment: `match()` returns an array or `null`. So `if (matches !== null)` should be fine (and it will please JSHint.) Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: It should be `isFinite(parseFloat(n))` in the first example. `isNumeric("5,000")` fails.

Comment: @m.spyratos, Well, `isFinite()` gives true if the passed value is a `finite` number and number `5,000` is a formatted string of number not a finite number.

Comment: @Starx, I agree. But if you don't support formatted string as input, then why do you use parse float in `isNaN`? I would suggest to either remove parse float from `isNaN` or add it to `isFinite` as well to be consisted.

Comment: @m.spyratos, If you do a `parseFloat('5,000')` it will give `5` as a result, which truncates most of the actual data. Its not designed to extract numeric/float value from a string but to separate if possible like `parseFloat('50.65 %')` will actually give `50.65` as a result. So its just used to check if `parseFloat` return `NaN`. Using a double negative check of `NaN` with `isFinite` ensure the value passed is numeric hence the solutions.

Comment: @Starx, I don't exactly agree with your point that `5,000` should be treated differently than `50.65 %`, which actually both return `false` by the method. I found out though that this method is being used in the `_.isFinite` method of Underscore.js and the purpose of `parseFloat` in the `isNaN` is to avoid some inconsistencies of the javascript's `isFinite` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27007535/1222409). Thanks!

Comment: @m.spyratos, Yes, of course it returns false. I was explaining about `parseFloat()` not the solution itself. It doesn't treat them differently, hence return false for both. Thanks for link, I will give it a read.

Comment: @Starx, Thanks for explaining!

Comment: For people not familiar with JavaScript regular expressions, you might want to explain what the regex is actually doing, particularly the trailing `g`.

Comment: This is not the answer since the title says **contains number** but this checks if the string is number.

Comment: There's no need for `+` in the regexp. Just matching 1 digit is enough.

Answer (score 46):

This is what you need.

```
      var hasNumber = /\d/;   
      hasNumber.test("ABC33SDF");  //true
      hasNumber.test("ABCSDF");  //false
```

Comment: this is an excellent answer I can't believe i never knew about this! thanks for sharing

Comment: Awesome bro, can't believed on this before testing. Thanks be blessed bro

Answer (score 23):

```
function validate(){    
    var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(re.test(document.getElementById("textboxID").value))
       alert('Valid Name.');
    else
       alert('Invalid Name.');      
}
```

Comment: I had to read the whole question to realize this actually answers the exact question asked. The question title is a little deceptive.

Answer (score 11):

It's not bulletproof by any means, but it worked for my purposes and maybe it will help someone.

```
var value = $('input').val();
 if(parseInt(value)) {
  console.log(value+" is a number.");
 }
 else {
  console.log(value+" is NaN.");
 }
```

Comment: ```Boolean(parseInt(3)) -> true; 
Boolean(parseInt("3")) -> true; 
Boolean(parseInt("three")) -> false```

Comment: It serves my purpose. Thank you

Comment: Be careful while using this ```parseInt("0")``` will also be false

Answer (score 9):

Using [Regular Expressions with JavaScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html). A regular expression is a special text string for describing a search pattern, which is written in the form of /pattern/modifiers where "pattern" is the regular expression itself, and "modifiers" are a series of characters indicating various options.

         *The [character class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) is the most basic regex concept after a literal match. It makes one small sequence of characters match a larger set of characters. For example, `[A-Z]` could stand for the upper case alphabet, and `\d` could mean any digit.*

From below example

- `contains_alphaNumeric` « It checks for string contains either letter or number (or) both letter and number. *The [hyphen (-) is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897392/5081877)*.
- `onlyMixOfAlphaNumeric` « It checks for string contain both [letters and numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928178/5081877) of any sequence order.

Example:

```javascript
function matchExpression( str ) {
    var rgularExp = {
        contains_alphaNumeric : /^(?!-)(?!.*-)[A-Za-z0-9-]+(?<!-)$/,
        containsNumber : /\d+/,
        containsAlphabet : /[a-zA-Z]/,

        onlyLetters : /^[A-Za-z]+$/,
        onlyNumbers : /^[0-9]+$/,
        onlyMixOfAlphaNumeric : /^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
    }

    var expMatch = {};
    expMatch.containsNumber = rgularExp.containsNumber.test(str);
    expMatch.containsAlphabet = rgularExp.containsAlphabet.test(str);
    expMatch.alphaNumeric = rgularExp.contains_alphaNumeric.test(str);

    expMatch.onlyNumbers = rgularExp.onlyNumbers.test(str);
    expMatch.onlyLetters = rgularExp.onlyLetters.test(str);
    expMatch.mixOfAlphaNumeric = rgularExp.onlyMixOfAlphaNumeric.test(str);

    return expMatch;
}

// HTML Element attribute's[id, name] with dynamic values.
var id1 = "Yash", id2="777", id3= "Yash777", id4= "Yash777Image4"
    id11= "image5.64", id22= "55-5.6", id33= "image_Yash", id44= "image-Yash"
    id12= "_-.";
console.log( "Only Letters:\n ", matchExpression(id1) );
console.log( "Only Numbers:\n ", matchExpression(id2) );
console.log( "Only Mix of Letters and Numbers:\n ", matchExpression(id3) );
console.log( "Only Mix of Letters and Numbers:\n ", matchExpression(id4) );

console.log( "Mixed with Special symbols" );
console.log( "Letters and Numbers :\n ", matchExpression(id11) );
console.log( "Numbers [-]:\n ", matchExpression(id22) );
console.log( "Letters :\n ", matchExpression(id33) );
console.log( "Letters [-]:\n ", matchExpression(id44) );

console.log( "Only Special symbols :\n ", matchExpression(id12) );
```

Out put:

```javascript
Only Letters:
  {containsNumber: false, containsAlphabet: true, alphaNumeric: true, onlyNumbers: false, onlyLetters: true, mixOfAlphaNumeric: false}
Only Numbers:
  {containsNumber: true, containsAlphabet: false, alphaNumeric: true, onlyNumbers: true, onlyLetters: false, mixOfAlphaNumeric: false}
Only Mix of Letters and Numbers:
  {containsNumber: true, containsAlphabet: true, alphaNumeric: true, onlyNumbers: false, onlyLetters: false, mixOfAlphaNumeric: true}
Only Mix of Letters and Numbers:
  {containsNumber: true, containsAlphabet: true, alphaNumeric: true, onlyNumbers: false, onlyLetters: false, mixOfAlphaNumeric: true}
Mixed with Special symbols
Letters and Numbers :
  {containsNumber: true, containsAlphabet: true, alphaNumeric: false, onlyNumbers: false, onlyLetters: false, mixOfAlphaNumeric: false}
Numbers [-]:
  {containsNumber: true, containsAlphabet: false, alphaNumeric: false, onlyNumbers: false, onlyLetters: false, mixOfAlphaNumeric: false}
Letters :
  {containsNumber: false, containsAlphabet: true, alphaNumeric: false, onlyNumbers: false, onlyLetters: false, mixOfAlphaNumeric: false}
Letters [-]:
  {containsNumber: false, containsAlphabet: true, alphaNumeric: true, onlyNumbers: false, onlyLetters: false, mixOfAlphaNumeric: false}
Only Special symbols :
  {containsNumber: false, containsAlphabet: false, alphaNumeric: false, onlyNumbers: false, onlyLetters: false, mixOfAlphaNumeric: false}
```

[java Pattern Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31242852/5081877) with Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using javascript. No need for Jquery or Regex

```
function isNumeric(n) 
{
  return !isNaN(n);
}
```

Comment: Overkill. Could be just `function isNumeric(n) { return !isNaN(n); }`

Comment: This also doesn't check to see if ANY character is a number. But I can think of a solution inspired by this.

Comment: This only checks if it is a number, not if it contains a number. "ABC123" would resolve to false, whereas it should resolve to true. Also why create an extra function instead of just if ( !isNaN(str) ) {} ?

Comment: Working in TS in following way
if (!isNaN(n)) {
......
}

Answer (score 4):

To test if any char is a number, without overkill❓, to be adapted as need.

```js
const s = "EMA618"

function hasInt(me){
  let i = 1,a = me.split(""),b = "",c = "";
  a.forEach(function(e){
   if (!isNaN(e)){
     console.log(`CONTAIN NUMBER «${e}» AT POSITION ${a.indexOf(e)} => TOTAL COUNT ${i}`)
     c += e
     i++
   } else {b += e}
  })
  console.log(`STRING IS «${b}», NUMBER IS «${c}»`)
  if (i === 0){
    return false
    // return b
  } else {
    return true
    // return +c
  }
}


hasInt(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to check it is to loop through the string and return true (or false depending on what you want) when you hit a number.

```
function checkStringForNumbers(input){
    let str = String(input);
    for( let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
              console.log(str.charAt(i));
        if(!isNaN(str.charAt(i))){           //if the string is a number, do the following
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` provides integers when the string begins with the representation of an integer:

```
(parseInt '1a')  is  1
```

..so perhaps:

```
isInteger = (s)->
  s is (parseInt s).toString()  and  s isnt 'NaN'

(isInteger 'a') is false
(isInteger '1a') is false
(isInteger 'NaN') is false
(isInteger '-42') is true
```

Pardon my CoffeeScript.

Comment: Basically, `parseInt('10m') /* returns 10*/` will do the trick **if** the string **starts** with a number. Otherwise returns NaN. If at all this behaviour is ok for you, consider `parseFloat('2.34million')` so you get 2.34 instead of losing money ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simple and easy way to extract numbers and string.

```js
str = "jdghj4874y6jfngvjbng"
let num = []
let strEx = []
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] >= 0) {
    num.push(str[i])
  } else {
    strEx.push(str[i])
  }
}
console.log('nums:', JSON.stringify(num))
console.log('chars:', JSON.stringify(strEx))
```

Comment: I think there is no need to convert object into stringy
Please put the reason
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code also helps in, **"To Detect Numbers in Given String"** when numbers found it stops its execution.

```
function hasDigitFind(_str_) {
  this._code_ = 10;  /*When empty string found*/
  var _strArray = [];

  if (_str_ !== '' || _str_ !== undefined || _str_ !== null) {
    _strArray = _str_.split('');
    for(var i = 0; i < _strArray.length; i++) {
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(_strArray[i]))) {
        this._code_ = -1;
        break;
      } else {
        this._code_ = 1;
      }
    }

  }
  return this._code_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code checks for same number, sequence number and reverse number sequence.

```
function checkNumSequnce(arrayNM2) {
    inseqCounter=1;
    continousSeq = 1;
    decsequenceConter = 1;
    var isequence = true;
    for (i=0;i<arrayNM2.length-1;i++) {
      j=i+1;
      if (arrayNM2[i] == arrayNM2[i+1]) { 
                if(inseqCounter > 1 || decsequenceConter > 1){
                    isequence =  false; break;
                }        
                 continousSeq++; 
                             
         }         
        else if (arrayNM2[j]- arrayNM2[i] == 1) {
            if(decsequenceConter > 1 || continousSeq > 1){
                isequence =  false; break;  
              }      
             inseqCounter++;               
                        
        } else if(arrayNM2[i]- arrayNM2[j] == 1){
              if(inseqCounter > 1 || continousSeq > 1){
                   isequence =  false; break;
               }
              decsequenceConter++;
        }else{
              isequence= false;
              break;
        }
  };

  console.log("isequence: "+ isequence); 

  };
```

Comment: This is undoubtedly the most confusing and verbose SO solution I have ever seen

Comment: @kshitij This is answer is working for sequential and repeated number validation. May be this answer is not 100% match for this question. But great logic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**We can check it by using `!/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(e)`**
Just run snippet and check.

```js
function handleValueChange() {
  if (!/[^a-zA-Z]/.test(document.getElementById('textbox_id').value)) {
      var x = document.getElementById('result');
      x.innerHTML = 'String does not contain number';
  } else {
    var x = document.getElementById('result');
    x.innerHTML = 'String does contains number';
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox_id" placeholder="Enter string here..." oninput="handleValueChange()">
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: this doesn't work for input `abc!` - the regex you have checks if its not an alphabet; this means even symbols like ! will be treated as number.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has addressed the body of the question:

> My end goal is to validate an input field. The input **may be either alphabetic or numeric**.
>
> -- op

So here is a function that returns a `boolean` answer,
`true` if the passed `input` has a `Number` value OR a strictly *alphabetic* string value,
`false` otherwise:

```js
const isAlphaOrNumeric = input => {
  if ('' === input.value.trim())
    return false // empty
    
  if (!Number.isNaN(Number(input.value)))
    return true //'number'

  return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(input.value.trim()) // 'alphabetic'
}
```

```js
const isAlphaOrNumeric = input => {
  if ('' === input.value.trim())
    return false

  if (!Number.isNaN(Number(input.value)))
    return true

  return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(input.value.trim())
}

const f = document.querySelector('form')
const test = f.querySelector('[name="test"]')
const test2 = f.querySelector('[name="test2"]')
const test3 = f.querySelector('[name="test3"]')
f.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(test.value, isAlphaOrNumeric(test))
  console.log(test2.value, isAlphaOrNumeric(test2))
  console.log(test3.value, isAlphaOrNumeric(test3))
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="test" value="abc"><br>
  <input name="test2" value="-3.14"><br>
  <input name="test3" value="AFF4B3"><br>
  <button>
    check it
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check whether string has number or not.

```
'test123'.split('').reduce((result,ch) => ch.charCodeAt(0) >= 48 && ch.charCodeAt(0) <= 57), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check_string(str){
  const number_pattern = /\d/;
  return number_pattern.test(str)
}

let sample_string = "Hello World 1234";
let is_string_contains_number = check_string(sample_string);
//output : true [if the string contains number in it]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function containsNumbers(inputString) {
    return /\d/.test(inputString);
}

// Example usage:
console.log(containsNumbers("Hello123")); // Output: true
console.log(containsNumbers("Hello"));    // Output: false
```

the containsNumbers function checks if the input string contains any digit (\d) using the test() method with a regular expression. If any digit is found in the input string, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false.

```
function containsNumber(str) {
  return /[0-9]/.test(str);
}

// Example usage:
console.log(containsNumber("Hello123")); // Output: true
console.log(containsNumber("Hello"));    // Output: false
```

return /[0-9]/.test(str);: This line contains the core logic of the function. Here's what it does:

/[0-9]/: This is a regular expression literal enclosed within /.../. [0-9] is a character class that matches any single digit from 0 to 9.
.test(str): This is a method of the regular expression object that tests whether the provided string str contains a match for the regular expression. It returns true if a match is found, otherwise false.

Answer (score -2):

You can also try lodash:

```
const isNumeric = number => 
  _.isFinite(_.parseInt(number)) && !_.isNaN(_.parseInt(number))
```