# jQuery to check if ID value has a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in **jQuery** to check if an ID value (Ex. `id="number1"`) contains a number?

The idea would be:

if (ID has a number which will come from a variable) then do something.

this is what I came up with so far but it only works with the first div:

```
    $("#tabsstyle li a").bind("click", function () {
        var numSlide = $(this).attr("rel");
        if ($('#slidesContainer div').attr('id').match(numSlide) ) {
        $('#slidesContainer div').fadeIn();
}
```

numSlide will store a number coming from one of the 'a' clicked and check that number will be included in the id value of '#slidesContainer div', once that checked then the right div will fadeIn.

HTML structure below:

```
<div id="slidesContainer">
  <div id="n1" class="slide">
    <h2>Web Development Tutorial</h2>
    <p><button class="test">N1</button></p>

  </div>
  <div id="n2" class="slide">
    <h2>Grunge Brushes, Anyone?</h2>
    <p><button class="test">N2</button></p>

  </div>
  <div id="n3" class="slide">
    <h2>How About Some Awesome Grunge Textures?</h2>
   <p><button class="test">N3</button></p>
  </div>
  <div id="n4" class="slide">
    <h2>'Tis the End, My Friend.</h2>
    <p><button class="test">N4</button></p>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: No, but some basic JavaScript functions will do it.

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778020/jquery-check-whether-an-input-string-contains-number)

Answer (score 4):

```
var id = $('#element').attr('id'); // #element will replace 
                                   // with your desired selector



id.match(/[0-9]/g)
```

***Checking***

```
if( id.match(/[0-9]/g) ) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following jquery plugin
https://github.com/jquery/globalize

That handles "numbers" a number can be an integer or a decimal, and a decimal number has different representations based on the culture :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` to build a function with [test](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) and a [regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to  check if a string contains a number.

```
 function hasNumber(t){
     //regular expression: /\d/g
     return /\d/g.test(t);
 }
```

And then use `jQuery` to check the value of the attribute `id`

```
 alert (hasNumber($('#checkMe').attr('id')))
```