# jQuery with Selenium form validation

Tags: jquery, selenium

I am trying to validate my form using Selenium ID but it's not passing the first name. I need it to only accept first name in letters no numbers.  Below is the code:

```
function validateFrName(){

        if (frName.val() == "1"){
         frName.addClass("error");
        $("#firstNameErrorMsg").text("First name can only contain letters.");
        $("#firstNameErrorMsg").addClass("error");
        return false;

    } else if (frName.val().length <3){
        frName.addClass("error");
        $("#firstNameErrorMsg").text("Please enter your first name.");
        $("#firstNameErrorMsg").addClass("error");
        return false;
    }else{
        frName.removeClass("error");
        $("#firstNameErrorMsg").text("OK");
        $("#firstNameErrorMsg").removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Leon smith, titling your question "Jquery please help me" isn't useful, a good title describing your issue is important.

Comment: please accept my apologies, this is my first time asking a question on here. Thank you

Comment: Ah, welcome on SO. Please read the [faq].

Comment: frName is how i identified FirstName on the html

Comment: again, welcome, I am confident that you can find a good answer to your question. Reading the FAQ is quick and painless

Comment: also, if frName a textbox? or a div/span/etc...?

Comment: @NathanKoop it is a text box where the user enters his first name. All i need really is a code to ONLY allow letters not a mix with numbers like steve1 or Sasha223. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vHzKn/1/

The problem is with how you are grabbing the frName.

I have added a variable called firstName and assigned it the value of the textbox with the id of frName

```
var firstName = $("#frName").val();
```

I then validate based on the firstName variable.

Please note that the code sample in the jsfiddle doesn't find all numbers etc... that is a separate question. You should probably use a javascript validation library for that.

EDIT: Look at [Check whether an input string contains number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778020/jquery-check-whether-an-input-string-contains-number) to find a regex to determine if a number exists in a string.

See this super simple jsfiddle with a jquery example: http://jsfiddle.net/XCYL7/

Comment: That helps alot but is there no way to add more numbers as i can only use jquery for this project? thanks for your help and time

Comment: thank you for your time and help. I have managed to get it working. Have a good day. Leon

Comment: @LeonSmith was this answer the one that helped you? If so then an upvote and an accept is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand your question correctly.
If you get your firstname via this "frName.val()", then why couldnt you try checking 
frName.val().substring(0,2)= 1 or 2 or 3 etc.
Please tell me some more detail if you didnt get with this..

Please try this also

```
function valid()
{
var k=true;
for(i=0;i<frName.val().length-1;i++)
{
if ( frName.val().substring(i,i+1)=0 ||   frName.val().substring(i,i+1)=1)
{
k=false;
}
}
return k;
}
```

Comment: Hello, the first If statement is just a mess around hence the matching to "1". I need some way to make it not accept e.g 1Steve or steve1 just letters only no numbers. Please try and help with easy coding like used above. Thanks

Comment: I am sorry for that misunderstanding. frName.val() will return your first name. correct?

Comment: i am abit confused as its my first time using jquery. How can i implement the code above into mine? sorry for being a pain!