# proper regex with boundary matches

Tags: regex

Here are my input strings:
**national fajfjlajllfsjakljf fj alkfjklajf  jafl fjlajl 

international 

jfalkj jalkfjda national 

inter-national 

international  

inter_national**

I want a regex which picks national only BUT not international or inter-national or inter_national.
What I'm trying is **\bnational\b**, this picks all cases except the first match in first line.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: `(?<!\S)national(?!\S)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want `national` which are at `start` or `end` or surrounded by `spaces`.You can use

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))national(?=\s|$)
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/20)

Answer (score 0):

**[regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862289/how-to-use-regex-in-java-to-pattern-match/31242852#31242852)**

```
String[] s = {"national", "fajfjlajllfsjakljf", "fj", "alkfjklajf" ,"jafl", "fjlajl" ,
        "international" ,
        "jfalkj jalkfjda national" ,
        "inter-national", 
        "international", 
        "inter_national"};
java.util.regex.Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(national)+$");
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (p.matcher(s[i]).find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("true");
    } 
}
```