# How to pull phrase out of a string

Tags: java, regex

how do i pull the "16" out for both

- Bar Foo Bar: Foo8:16 Foo Bar Bar foo barz
- 8:16 Foo Bar Bar foo barz

Here is what i have tried

```
String V,Line ="Bar Foo Bar: Foo8:16 Foo Bar Bar foo barz";
V = Line.substring(Line.indexOf("([0-9]+:[0-9]+)+")+1);
V = V.substring(V.indexOf(":")+1, V.indexOf(" "));
System.out.println(V);
```

And here is the error i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1955)  
    at Indexing.Index(Indexing.java:94)  
    at Indexing.main(Indexing.java:24)
```

I tested the regex("([0-9]+:[0-9]+)+") at http://regexr.com/ and it correctly highlight the "8:16"

Comment: What is output expect?

Comment: You need to use the Java Regex library for list kind of search the way you want to do it. You cannot just do `indexOf` with a regex.

Comment: the [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) function doesn't take a regex

Comment: 16 is the expected output

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Regex in Java to pattern match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862289/how-to-use-regex-in-java-to-pattern-match)

Comment: ahhh... i was confusing it with the replace, i had gotten used to using regex Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place the capturing group on the second `[0-9]+` (or an equivalent, `\d+`) and use a **[`Matcher#find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)**:

```
String value1 = "Bar Foo Bar: Foo8:16 Foo Bar Bar foo barz";
String pattern1 = "\\d+:(\\d+)"; // <= The first group is the \d+ in round brackets
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(value1);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // <= Print the value captured by the first group
else
    System.out.println("false");
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/RODLKQ)

Comment: Good answer. This is the safest way to do it.

Comment: what would have to go wrong for matcher.find() to return false

Comment: If a pattern does not match anywhere inside the input string, the returned result is false. Actually, in most cases that `else` statement is omitted, I just added it for code completeness.

Answer (score 0):

String.indexOf(String str) doesn't take a regex. It takes a String.

You can simply do this:

```
String V, Line = "Bar Foo Bar: Foo8:16 Foo Bar Bar foo barz";
V = Line.substring(Line.indexOf("16"), Line.indexOf("16") + 2);
System.out.println(V);
```

Or to make it look neater, you can replace this line:

```
V = Line.substring(Line.indexOf("16"), Line.indexOf("16") + 2);
```

with:

```
int index = Line.indexOf("16");
V = Line.substring(index, index + 2);
```

Comment: You are going around in circles.  BTW i do not know the value of the "16" or the "8". only that they have a colon in the middle, and may have more colons around it

Comment: If the value is stored in a variable you can do the same thing, except you would do this: Line.indexOf(String.valueOf(value));
How exactly am I going in circles?

Comment: because if we know what `value` is then we can just do `V = value`

Comment: Fair enough, so you want find the string immediately after :?

Comment: 1,2,3 - but it may be the 2nd ":" of 2 or 5th of 8, IDK, but it will have 1-3 digits before and after it.

Comment: If the answer above worked for you then, I'm not going to spend any resources trying to figure this out. If it didn't, let me know I'll see what I can come up with.