# Underscore.js calling isNaN after isFinite function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In Underscore.js library, there is a function named `isFinite` returning 'true' if the value is a number. Considering that the built-in function `isFinite` of Javascript is already returning 'true' if the value passed as argument is a number, why we also need to call `!isNaN(parseFloat(obj))`?

```
// Is a given object a finite number?
  _.isFinite = function(obj) {
    return isFinite(obj) && !isNaN(parseFloat(obj));
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This covers the case of `isFinite("")`, `isFinite(null)` and `isFinite(false)` all returning `true`, because `isFinite` blindly converts its argument to a number and treats any of these like `0`.

Starting with the numeric conversion...

```
Number("") // 0
Number(false) // 0
Number(null) // 0
Number(undefined) // NaN
```

... `isFinite` has some surprising results:

```
isFinite("") // true
isFinite(false) // true
isFinite(null) // true
isFinite(undefined) // false
```

Meanwhile, `_.isFinite` returns something more like you might expect, because `parseFloat` returns `NaN` for all these values

```
_.isFinite("") // false
_.isFinite(false) // false
_.isFinite(null) // false
_.isFinite(undefined) // false
```

Note that you can get the same explicit checking with `Number.isFinite`, which doesn't attempt to convert its argument (but which is less well supported across browsers):

```
Number.isFinite("") // false
Number.isFinite(false) // false
Number.isFinite(null) // false
Number.isFinite(undefined) // false
```

Comment: Hardly "blindly". [*isFinite*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.5) converts the argument to a number (using the internal [*ToNumber* method](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)), then works with the result. So the first set of results are to be expected.

Comment: @RobG It blindly invokes `ToNumber` on whatever you pass it, with no attempt to further inspect what it's receiving, yielding the pretty surprising behavior that `isFinte(null)` is `true`. I'd call that "blindly".

Comment: Granted, `null != 0` but `Number(null) == 0` is a bit weird, but who does that anyway? I guess type conversion is used so `isFinite('2')` works (and `Number.isFinte('2')` doesn't). Note that [*Number.isFinite*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) is an experimental ECMA-262 ed 6 draft feature and not available in many browsers in use.

Comment: Thank you very much meagar! I found this very useful link about type coercion a couple of years ago: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/ While reading your answer, the light goes on :) In conclusion, javascript try to convert everything to a number when an expression is passed to a function who need a boolean expression. In this case, it's like isFinite of Javascript try internally something like 'if (argument){return true} where the argument will be coerced with the rules of the link that I forward. Do I say something stupid?