# How to check if String has a Number?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this function :

```
function hasNumber(word) {
    return /^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(word)
}

console.log(hasNumber('some text'));        //true
console.log(hasNumber('some text2'));       //true
```

but it always returns true
Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: did you checked this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/javascript-get-number-from-string

Comment: you are looking for letters. the ^ here is the start of the string and not the negation operator.

Comment: The examples you give both return false when I try it. http://jsfiddle.net/zbxvpo72/

Comment: It seems like you used the expression from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5778085/218196). Make sure to also read the question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function hasNumber( str ){
  return /\d/.test( str );
}
```

<sub>results:</sub>

```
hasNumber(0)     // true
hasNumber("0")   // true
hasNumber(2)     // true
hasNumber("aba") // false
hasNumber("a2a") // true
```

While the above will return *truthy* as soon the function encounters **one** *Number* `\d`
if you want to be able **return an Array of the matched results**:

```
function hasNumber( str ){
  return str.match( /\d+/g );
}
```

<sub>results:</sub>

```
hasNumber( "11a2 b3 c" );  // ["11", "2", "3"]
hasNumber( "abc" );        // null
if( hasNumber( "a2" ) )    // "truthy statement"
```

where `+` in `/\d+/g` is to match *one or more* Numbers (therefore the "11" in the above result) and the `g` *Global* RegExp flag is to continue iterating till the end of the passed string.

[Advanced_Searching_With_Flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)
[RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: @FelixKling exactly, we're looking for just a single number in order to be `truthy` therefore the `+` *or more* iterator is not needed.