# Javascript method to check for digits within a string (validation of input data)

Tags: javascript, validation, business-process-management

Im trying to implement a validation for an input field in IBM BPM. 
Im not really familiar with java script but I try to get method that returns
ture if a string contains any numbers.

awdadw = valid
     awdawd**2**d = invalid

I tried this method:

```
function hasNumbers(t)
{
    var pattern=new RegExp("^[A-Za-z]+$"); 
    return pattern.test(t); // true if string. Returns false for numbers
}
```

When I try this function, it says that method / variable RegExp is unknown. Since it is rather basci stuff I hope to get some sources where this topic is explained.

Comment: Your code work for me in FF12 (https://jsfiddle.net/k7x2mn1e/).

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778020/check-whether-an-input-string-contains-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
function validate(){    
var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
if(re.test(document.getElementById("inputID").value))
   alert('Valid Name.');
else
   alert('Invalid Name.');      
  }
```

Comment: worked for me thanks. but I modified it a bid for my needs

Comment: but this code then does not allow "-" which is necessary for some names. How can I build this function, to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on adre3wap this worked for me:

```
function validate(t){
  var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if(re.test(t))
     return false;
  else
     return true;
}
```