# Method to check if label is empty is not working

Tags: java, is-empty

I am working on a program which uses jLabels and I need to check if label is empty or not. If it's empty it should just pop up a note that it's empty and nothing else, but it actually throws a lot of errors. I'm using label.getText().isEmpty(). 
 
Here's the code:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(najboljsi1.getText())<1||Integer.parseInt(najboljsi1.getText())>17||najboljsi1.getText().isEmpty()||
       Integer.parseInt(najboljsi2.getText())<1||Integer.parseInt(najboljsi2.getText())>17||najboljsi2.getText().isEmpty()||
       Integer.parseInt(najboljsi3.getText())<1||Integer.parseInt(najboljsi3.getText())>17||najboljsi3.getText().isEmpty()||
       Integer.parseInt(najslabsi1.getText())<1||Integer.parseInt(najslabsi1.getText())>17||najslabsi1.getText().isEmpty()||
       Integer.parseInt(najslabsi2.getText())<1||Integer.parseInt(najboljsi2.getText())>17||najslabsi2.getText().isEmpty()||
       Integer.parseInt(najslabsi3.getText())<1||Integer.parseInt(najslabsi3.getText())>17||najslabsi3.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        jLabel101.setForeground(Color.red);
        jLabel101.setText("Eno ali več vnesenih števil ni v pravilnem obsegu (1-16)!");
    }
    else
    {
        jLabel101.setText("");
        int a=Integer.parseInt(najboljsi1.getText());
        tabela[a-1]+=3;
        int b=Integer.parseInt(najboljsi2.getText());
        tabela[b-1]+=2;
        int c=Integer.parseInt(najboljsi3.getText());
        tabela[c-1]+=1;
        int d=Integer.parseInt(najslabsi1.getText());
        tabela[d-1]-=3;
        int e=Integer.parseInt(najslabsi2.getText());
        tabela[e-1]-=2;
        int f=Integer.parseInt(najslabsi3.getText());
        tabela[f-1]-=1;
        najboljsi1.setText("");
        najboljsi2.setText("");
        najboljsi3.setText("");
        najslabsi1.setText("");
        najslabsi2.setText("");
        najslabsi3.setText("");
        count++;
        jLabel1.setText("Učenec "+count);
    }
```

Everything else in if statement works ok, if value is lower than 1 or higher than 16, it throws a pop up.

Comment: Could you add what error are you getting ? Also, najboljsi1.getText().isEmpty() can be the first condition in the 'if' statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must test `najboljsi1.getText().isEmpty()` BEFORE any parsing of `najboljsi1.getText()`.
Your if would become:

```
if(najboljsi1.getText().isEmpty()||Integer.parseInt(najboljsi1.getText())<1||Integer.parseInt(najboljsi1.getText())>17||
       najboljsi2.getText().isEmpty()||Integer.parseInt(najboljsi2.getText())<1||Integer.parseInt(najboljsi2.getText())>17||
etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do  Integer.parseInt(najboljsi2.getText()) on a label with the textn "" (empty String), it won't be an integer. An exception will be thrown.

Comment: Should I check if ist it empty before lower and higher?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in the use of the "Integer.parseInt" without any check! If, for example, the variable contains an empty string, it will throw an Exception and your if clause will never work!

I would manage the situation with a double check.

1. Check if it is already a number (this guide could help
   [check-if-variable-is-a-number-in-javascript](https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/check-if-variable-is-a-number-in-javascript/))
2. Then, if it is a string, check if it is empty and if it actually contains a string (the following post could also help [check-whether-an-input-string-contains-a-number-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778020/check-whether-an-input-string-contains-a-number-in-javascript))

Ps. Sorry, I modified the answer with some extra links