# Check if string contains number? If yes then replace that number with another string

Tags: javascript, string

I m having a string, I need to check if that string contains any number or not. I found so many answers which only returns true or false [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28813213/6804648).
But what I want to do is identify that number and replace it with another string.
For example,

```
let myString = "/example/123/anotherstring"
```

or

```
let myString = "/example/anotherstring/123"
```

String can be anything like above.
Expected output is 123 should be replaced by any other string. like

```
let expectedString = "/example/replaced/anotherstring"
```

or

```
let expectedString = "/example/anotherstring/replaced"
```

I Know one way to solve this is, loop this string and find the position of number and then replace that. but I don't want to do that. Is there any better way to do this?

**NOTE**: The number can be anything, It's not static/known number. So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) does not help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so, use `string.replace(/\d+/g, 'any other string')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @bugs. I have added a note. in question. please check

Comment: @UshmaJoshi For any number you can use the regex: `\d+`, you can use regex to match any number and replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for this, pass a required regex to fit your requirement.

```js
let myString = "/example/123/anotherstring" 
let newString = myString.replace(/\d+/g, "replaced")
console.log(newString)

 myString = "/example/anotherstring/123"
 newString = myString.replace(/\d+/g, "replaced")
 console.log(newString)
```

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh, sorry I didn't read your comment in the question, I have read it now. Its a co-incidence that I used the same regex which you had already answered in your comment. And this regex is quite natural and comes to mind first. My answer was incorrect initially coz I did it in hurry.

Comment: no, it's not a coincidence, it's the only regex that works :p I was being "funny" :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\d+`.

```js
let myString = "/example/123/anotherstring" 

const checkNums = (str) => str.replace(/\d+/g,"replaced")

console.log(checkNums(myString))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular expression to replace all numbers with your alternative string:

```js
const myString = "/example/123/anotherstring";
const expectedString = myString.replace(/[0-9]+/g, "alternativestring")
console.log(expectedString);
```