# How to detect when Shift+NumKey is pressed in Javascript keyup event?

Tags: javascript

I've written the following code that writes to the console "true" if the [Shift] was pressed on a keyup even and "false" otherwise.

```
<script>
    var el = document.getElementById("myInput");
    el.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {            
        console.log(e.shiftKey);            
    });
</script>
```

For some reason, this code doesn't work when the event is triggered by pressing a number on the 10-key.  If I hold Shift and press Numpad5, it logs false.  I see the same behavior in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

I need to be able to detect if the user is holding [Shift] when a number on the 10-key is pressed.

Edit: In response to @sagar's comment, I tested specifically with the keys 1-10 because that is what I expect my user's to press.  Other keys will be ignored for the time being.  I want to be able to tell when the user presses a key for a digit 1-10 and whether or not [Shift] was pressed.

Comment: with other keys (instead of num) code works properly?

Comment: When testing your code it worked as you desired. Perhaps there is a difference in how your keyboard is responding? Is it a laptop with a function key lock or something else interfering? Try using a different keyboard?

Comment: @BA_Webimax I guess you're right, on my keyboard it didn't even log anything since there's no "Shift-based" key on the numpad (Or that's what I think at least)

Comment: I think there is some kind of flag turning ON /OFF while num lock is ON/OFF. That generates unexpected behaviour. As I tested this over my laptop turning on/off num lock in both cases result changes. If Num Lock off it logs true otherwise false

Comment: Moreover, on analysing logs I found if you turn on the num lock and press shift + num pad (numbers only) there will be two events. One for shift key and another for number key. Possibly it is OS-level interpretation of num lock, num pad and shift key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is somehow a limitation of the Windows operating system and I have no idea why this limitation exists.  I've seen examples on StackOverflow of developers encountering this same issue in other contexts.

For now, here's a solution that seems to work.  I don't like it and I think I shouldn't have to do this, but this is the best thing I could find.

I've discovered that when NumLock is on, if I hold [Shift] and press [Num5], there is a keyup event from [Shift] fired immediately before the keydown event for [Num5].  On my workstation, if I grab timestamps of these two events, they will be 5 ms or less part.  I simply wrote code that checks these two timestamps and if they are 10 ms apart or less, my application responds to the input considering that the user was holding [Shift] and pressing [Num5].

Since this code runs in a browser, I presume that other platforms will not have this limitation and it still does check for the event to indicate that [Shift] was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

you can base your condition on `e.getModifierState("NumLock")` `status` if it's ON or OFF because when it's ON your `e.shiftKey` is `false` and if it's off your `e.shiftKey` is `true`

press on the `Num lock` to test

```js
var el = document.getElementById("myInput");
el.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {

  console.log(e.getModifierState("NumLock"))
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me that NumLock has anything to do with it.  However, I still need to know if [Shift] is pressed.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: yes you're right, I spend some time with that and i figure out that when numbers lock is active the `e.codeKey`  between 95 and 105 returns always false even with `e.shiftKey` sorry i didn't find something works

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with the key numbers that the user must press to perform this action:

```js
const KeysEnum = {
        "ENTER": 16,
        "SHIFT": 13,
}

let keysPressed = {
};

const handleEventShiftAndEnterPress = () => {
      console.log ('User Press Shift Enter');
}

window.document.addEventListener ('keydown', function (event) {
    keysPressed[event.keyCode.toString()] = true;
    if (keysPressed [KeysEnum.SHIFT] && keysPressed [KeysEnum.ENTER]) {
       handleEventShiftAndEnterPress ();
       keysPressed [KeysEnum.SHIFT] = false; 
    keysPressed [KeysEnum.ENTER] = false;
    }
});
```

**as long as you control the keystroke object, you can do and know the state of each key whenever you like, so it's easy to do what you need :)**

Comment: It had occurred to me to try something like this.  It sounds like a lot of extra work and it would break if the user shifted the focus away with the mouse while holding down keys.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem of using keyCode to detect SHIFT instead of using e.shiftKey. I use it for shortcut keys with an Enum and a keystroke object. Works great :) What is your intention in using shiftKey? Can you detail what you want to do?

Comment: My intention is straightforward: I want the program to listen for keystrokes on the numpad and perform one action when a key is pressed if [Shift] is held and a different action otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but is a possible work-around. If you could use Alt instead of Shift, it works as expected (with num-lock on), and even allows the user to enter multiple digits while the Alt key is held:

```
    var  keyLog = "";
    const handleKeyboard = (e) => {
      if (e.type === 'keydown' && e.altKey) {
        if(e.key != "Alt") {
            keyLog+= e.key;
        }
      }
      if (e.type === 'keyup' && !e.altKey) {
            if(keyLog) {
                    console.log(keyLog);
                    keyLog="";
            }
      }
    }
      const events = ['keydown', 'keyup']
      events.forEach(name => document.addEventListener(name, handleKeyboard))
```

And, if Alt is held, you can detect whether the Shift key is held as well. You just have to reinterpret the descriptions into numbers:

```
    var keyLog="";
    const shiftNbrs=['Insert', 'End', 'ArrowDown', 'PageDown', 'ArrowLeft', 'Clear', 'ArrowRight', 'Home', 'ArrowUp', 'PageUp']
    document.onkeyup = function(e) {
            if(!e.altKey) {
                    if(keyLog) {
                            let type="Alt";
                            let z=keyLog;
                            if(keyLog.indexOf("Shift") > -1) {
                                    type+="/Shift";
                                    z="";
                                    let y = keyLog.split("Shift");
                                    y.forEach(a=> {if(a)z+=shiftNbrs.indexOf(a)});
                            }
                            console.log(type+": "+z);
                            keyLog="";
                    }
            }
    }
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
            if (e.repeat) return;
            let ev = e || window.event;
            ev.preventDefault();
            if(e.altKey) {
                if(e.key != "Alt") {
                    keyLog+= e.key;
                }
                return true;
            }
            // processing of regular keys...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a little bit of a special case, special key + numbers.

The key event contains an entry `shiftKey` (`ctrlKey` as well).

To handle numbers from both the right num pad and the top numbers keys, we can test to see if `event.code` contains a number.

```js
document.addEventListener ('keydown', function (e) {
    /* If shift key is down */
    if (e.shiftKey) {
         /* Test if e.code contains numbers */
         if (/\d/.test(e.code)){
               console.log("SHIFTKEY + NUMBER");
         }  
    }
},false)
```

This is for the detection, now the goal is to extract the number from that string:

```js
let keys = []
document.addEventListener ('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
         if (/\d/.test(e.code)){
               hasInt(e.code)
               console.log("SHIFTKEY + NUMBER " + keys[keys.length-1])
               console.log(keys)
         }
         
    }
},false)

/* Extract numbers from string */
/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/56510812/2494754 */
function hasInt(me){
  let i = 1,a = me.split(""),b = "",c = "";
  a.forEach(function(e){
   if (!isNaN(e)){
     c += e
     i++
   } else {b += e}
 })
 keys.push(+c)
}
```

```html
Hold SHIFT + any numbers
```

Comment: This is not the answer.  In my question, I already showed that I was looking at the value of e.shiftKey and it reads as false even when [Shift] is pressed.  It looks like this has something to do with NumLock.

Comment: This is not the answer but a working solution to your problem.

Comment: It is not a working solution to my problem because it depends on the value of e.shiftKey being true when the [Shift] key is pressed and false otherwise.  When NumLock is on and the num pad keys are pressed, e.shiftKey is always false.