# How to check if a text input string on change has a number using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check if a text input, on change, has a number in the string without using regex and only using just javascript?

For example (this may not be a good approach, I am unsure):

```
const passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");
passwordInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (e.target.value contains a number) {
        console.log("Must contain a number.")
    }
})
```

Comment: You can check each character separately.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778020/check-whether-an-input-string-contains-a-number-in-javascript for solution.

Please note that one digit is a "number". Just verify that this is what you want

Comment: [Off-topic]: you can use the `input` event instead of `change` for instant checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over it, and check each character, you can use `!isNaN(x)` to check if a `x` can be converted to a number, and `x.trim() !== ''` to filter out whitespaces (thanks to [@Lain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4728913/lain) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222209/how-to-check-if-a-text-input-string-on-change-has-a-number-using-javascript/62222416#comment110047004_62222416) that `isNaN` returns `false` for whitespaces):

```js
function hasNumbers(string){
  return Array.prototype.some.call(string, c => !isNaN(c) && c.trim())
}

const passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");
passwordInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (hasNumbers(e.target.value)) {
        console.log("Contains a number.")
    } else {
        console.log("Doesn't contain a number.")
    }
})
```

```html
<input id="password" >
```

Comment: Sure: `!isNaN(' ')`