# PHP allow letters and minus but not repeating minus

Tags: php, regex

I would like to allow in any charsets (latin, hebrew, cyrillic but not unicode emojis) all letter and minus (-), but it should not allow to use the minus more then once per time and not on start and end:

```
YaMo -> OK
Ya-Mo -> OK
Ya-Mo-Ga -> OK
Ya--Mo -> FALSE
Ya---Mo -> FALSE
-Ya -> FALSE
-Ya-Mo- -> FALSE
Ya- -> FALSE
Yo-Mo- Mo -> FALSE
Yo-Mo -Go -> FALSE
```

So far I have:

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L} -]+$/', $post['firstname'])
```

It don't take care about multiple occurence and if is on start or end. 
Exist there any regex approach to do it?

As workaround I now check with substr first and last letter != '-' and check with strpos for '--'.

the proposed similiar duplicate is wrong, as it not work as it should, it allow:
Yo-Mo- Mo

Comment: Use `'/^\p{L}+(?:[ -]\p{L}+)*$/u'` - https://regex101.com/r/Uv7NUb/1. I think the hyphen rule also pertains to the space, right?

Comment: I found the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897392/3832970) where all you need is to replace `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` with your `[\p{L} -]+`. Also, add `u` to make the regex fully Unicode compatible and make PCRE treat the input text as Unicode chars.

Comment: can a string without hiphens(-) be also allowed ?

Comment: @aelor yes it can

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the proposed duplicate is wrong I found out it don't work as it should.

Comment: **Do you want to allow spaces?** If not, *why is it in your pattern?* You say, `Yo-Mo- Mo` should not be matched, but why? If you do not want spaces, try my first suggestion then, but take out space, `'/^\p{L}+(?:-\p{L}+)*$/u'`.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew space is only allowed between two words. Yo-Mo- Mo -> not allowed but Yo-Mo Mo is allowed, the idea behind is to allow real names only.

Comment: So, my top comment regex is working for you, right? Please test.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes the top comment solution works, thank you. I concenctrated on the proposed duplicate solution and missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you may use is

```
'/^\p{L}+(?:[ -]\p{L}+)*$/u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uv7NUb/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{L}+` - 1+ letters
- `(?:[ -]\p{L}+)*` - 0+ repetitions of

  - `[ -]` - a space or `-`
  - `\p{L}+` - 1+ letters
- `$` - end of string (replace with `\z` to only match the very end of string, and not also before a final LF symbol).

The modifier `u` is necessary to make it work without issues with Unicode strings.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
^\w+(-\w+)*$
```

- \w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) one or more
  times
- (-\w+)* makes sure that the word characters along with hiphen
  appears zero or more times

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/UpDD97/2)