# How to match regex for specific character at start, middle and end

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which is invalid if it has

```
  _ at start ||
  _ at end ||
  more than one consecutive _ in the middle
```

but it is valid if more than one non consecutive `_` found in a string

examples are

```
"'test_test_test" - valid 
"test_" - invalid
"_test" - invalid
"test_____test" - invalid
```

I am trying different pattern to match all this condition into one but doesn't seem to work for e.g.`("^[__]+") or ("^[_]+") or ("^[_]$+")`

If you could help me with regex and some explanation, I would really appreciate!

Comment: The easiest pattern is `^[^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*$`, adapted [from this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897384/3832970).

Comment: but it fails for test_ and _test

Comment: `test_` and `_test` are not matched with `^[^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*$`

Comment: ah! sorry my bad. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(_\\w*)|(\\w*_{2,}+\\w*)|(\\w*_$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("te_st_");
System.out.println("Is string invalid: "+ m.matches());
```

See the result: https://ideone.com/hwMzL1

For more details: [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)