# Regex for IMG filename

Tags: regex

I want to test if a img filename (jpg) is valid in PHP. The files should look like this:

test-file.jpg

test-123-test.jpg

123-456-thumbnail.jpg

I tried the following regex:

```
([a-z0–9-])+.(jpg)
```

It works fine, but still allows filnames like "test--123----.jpg", but I just want to allow one "-".

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to disallow more than 1 dash consecutively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897353/regex-to-disallow-more-than-1-dash-consecutively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase the regex as:

```regex
^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.jpg$
```

### Demo

This expresses a filename having one or more terms, each separated by a single hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this.

```regex
^(\w+([-]{1})?)+[.]jpg$
```

Here is a link for test purpose : https://regex101.com/r/Fo7b9c/1/

Comment: this can also be like `^(\w+-?)+\.jpg$` no need of `{1}` here

Comment: Indeed, it was just a proposition but there is hundreds of way of solving that I guess.